# How to find address of an Excel Range in vb.net whose value has "New Line" In it?

Tags: vb.net

I want to find address of an excel cell using find method.

What i tried was 
1] ws.UsedRange.Rows.Find("SomeText \r\n MoreText").Address

2] ws.UsedRange.Rows.Find("SomeText \n MoreText").Address

3] dim strVar as String = Environment.Newline
   ws.UsedRange.Rows.Find("SomeText "+ strVar +" MoreText").Address

But Nothing is working.

What am i missing?

Comment: Excel uses a linefeed character to split multi-line cell strings. That would correspond to the "\n" escape sequence in your example. However VB does not pre-process strings for escape sequences, that is a feature of C style language compilers. Use `ChrW(10) ` to define the new line character.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declar a string variable and then assign address to it, something like below

Dim ad as string 
ad = ws.UsedRange.Find("your text").Address
Msgbox ad 'to verify address is found.

This is showing the address of text to be found for me.
See if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @D.Ace ill try

Comment: Not Working @D.Ace